# Unity3D Transform.position not Matching Debug.Log Position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I log a GameObject's position to the console I get a different value in the console than in the inspector.

So, whenever I try to move the object on click, it just moves to a wild position. Am I doing anything wrong?

[image: Image for more detail]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the position you set in the inspector is the local position (that is, the position relative to the parent), while [`transform.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) gives you the absolute position (the position relative to the world origin).

To get the local position you can use [`transform.localPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html).

Comment: Awesome ! Did not think of this, totally forgot. Thanks alot !

Comment: @Wesley Also note that the `ToString()` method of Vector3 objects rounds the value to the nearest `0.1`, which may also cause confusion ("Why is the debug saying it's 0? It's definitely not zero!")

Answer (score 2):

In the Inspector window you see only the **local** transforms of gameobject.
While the `Debug.Log` writes gameobject's **global** position in world.
Try to change the code to:

```
Debug.Log(transform.localPosition);
```